# Database connection with smart contract

Tags: solidity, database

I am developing a Dapp, which has a smart contract in solidity and uses truffle framework. My smart contract has a constructor that takes a value as an argument
I want to initialize this smart contract from truffle framework in node.js
But the value that I need to pass to initialize has to be fetched from a database(mongoDB). How can this be done?
Can we write fetching this code logic in 2_deploy_contracts.js?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you can do it with JavaScript, you integrate into your migration process.

Hope it helps.